# Updating multiple links in multiple workbooks

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have 3 workbooks. Call them A,B and C.

B receives data from C via a link

A receives data from B, including data B received from C

I want to update all the links when I open A

I get that a Workbook_open event is used from ThisWorkbook in Workbook A, in VBA

I have spent many hours attempting to get this to work to no avail

Tiny bits of my code work but have troubles with updating links, which stalls the code that starts on A opening

Comment: This is a cop out, but I assume you can't just merge the workbooks?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Each workbook is for a seperate financial year and I need to keep them seperate. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

So the way you are doing this is bad, in the sense that you have two layers of inheritance, leading to needless complication. If you use the instructions [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/create-and-manage-links-to-other-workbooks-HA001054812.aspx) to simply pull data from both workbooks your troubles will be solved.

This bypasses completely how to do what amounts to two layers of inheritance, events, and the like. I think that is a good thing. If you want to have someone figure out how to do that specifically, I think that is a topic for another question.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Turns out I was trying too hard. The links update without any help from me. All I want to do is disable this message.

Comment: Sorry, wrong button. Disable this message. This workbook contains one or more links that cannot be updated. You get continue or edit links options. I just want to disable this box or prevent it from appearing. Thanks

Comment: Ask it as a new question, but you might want to try "On Error Resume Next" WARNING it does not fix the error, just pretends that it did not happen.